# IdentityServer 4 Https over self signed certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, certificate, identityserver4

Locally, I have a set of web applications all accessible through a single login.
For this purpose I have adopted Identity Server 4.

Once the applications were published on a local server, not accessible remotely, I generated an SSL certificate via openssl and set IIS to use it.

In particular, my machine is reachable via a local dns.
For example my machine has ip: 192.168.15.3 and the alias is app.server.lan

If I connect to the home page of the site (app.server.lan) Google Chrome detects that the site is safe.
But when I try to access an app and then start the connection between the application and the identity server I get an errore page with the following error in the log:

```
2021-02-04 14:09:04.6785|1|ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware|An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. 
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'. 
---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'. 
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The PPI is hidden is: .well-known/openid-configuration that is visibile if i check via browser.

How can i solve?
Can I use IdentityServer 4 without https?

[image]

Where you see black line is app.server.lan

5000 is identityserver port

443 is main app port

5001 to 5005 is other app port

Comment: what is the address for Identity Server? different port same app.server.lan?

Comment: app.server.lan:5000

Comment: Can you share iis bindings? Or iiespress apps please!

Comment: addedd image to op

Comment: I guess your client does not like your self signed certificate? Better to get a real certificate, like using LetsEncrypt

Comment: can you try adding that certificate to Trusted Root Certifications Authority in you windows machine - Certificates Store? I am guessing in your OpenIdConnect section you are using proer https protocols, right?

Comment: Alrady in trusted root certifications authority

Comment: I see now that the CA root say that the scope Is server only.. maybe i generate a wrong ssl certificate? Has to be server and client?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

below is the code to get the certioficat from the store:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
using (var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
    certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
        X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
        "<THUMBPRINT>", // Change this with the thumbprint of your certifiacte
        false);

    if (certCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        cert = certCollection[0];
    }
}
```

and

```
if(cert == null)
{
    // If the certificate is not installed, you might be in development and want to ise the developer credebntials
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
}
else
{
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddSigningCredential(cert);
}
```

make sure that the application pool identity that is running the IdentityServer application has access to the private keys. If not, give it permission.

set Load User Profile to "true" in iis application pool advance setting.

Comment: My problem is not uploading the certificate for signing. I generate the certificate, and insert it by loading it from file correctly.
The problem is the certificate itself which is not seen as valid because it is probably self signed.
If I use a purchased certificate, everything works.

Comment: @V_Martusciello you could post the solution as an answer and mark it. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: I don't have a solution yet. I'm using a valid not self signed certificate for now.